# Creating MySQL table getting SQLSTATE[42000] error 1118. Row size too large

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have a Laravel Migration (creating a table) and it is giving me this error below.  THe problem is, I'm actually just duplicating a table that the State of Florida provides and provide the schema and what to set each field to.  I have no idea how I could change it.

This is on mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.40, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting
  BLOBs, is 65535. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
```

**The full migration is below:**

```
    Schema::create('rets_property_res_bonita', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->decimal('Acres',14,4)->nullable();
        $table->integer('ActiveOpenHouseCount')->nullable();
        $table->text('AdditionalRooms')->nullable();
        $table->text('Amenities')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('AmenityRecFee',17,2)->nullable();
        $table->string('AmenRecFreq')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('ApplicationFee',17,2)->nullable();
        $table->text('Approval')->nullable();
        $table->integer('ApproxLivingArea')->nullable();
        $table->string('AssociationMngmtPhone')->nullable();
        $table->integer('BathsFull')->nullable();
        $table->integer('BathsHalf')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('BathsTotal',7,2)->nullable();
        $table->text('BedroomDesc')->nullable();
        $table->string('Bedrooms')->nullable();
        $table->integer('BedsTotal')->nullable();
        $table->string('Block')->nullable();
        $table->text('BoatAccess')->nullable();
        $table->char('BuilderProductYN',1)->nullable();
        $table->text('BuildingDesc')->nullable();
        $table->string('BuildingDesign')->nullable();
        $table->string('BuildingNumber')->nullable();
        $table->string('BuyersCountryOfResidence')->nullable();
        $table->char('CableAvailableYN',1)->nullable();
        $table->string('CanalWidth')->nullable();
        $table->string('CarportDesc')->nullable();
        $table->integer('CarportSpaces')->nullable();
        $table->integer('CDOM')->nullable();
        $table->string('City')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('CloseDate')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('ClosePrice',16,2)->nullable();
        $table->bigInteger('CoListAgent_MUI')->nullable();
        $table->string('CoListAgentDirectWorkPhone')->nullable();
        $table->string('CoListAgentEmail')->nullable();
        $table->string('CoListAgentFullName')->nullable();
        $table->string('CoListAgentMLSID')->nullable();
        $table->bigInteger('CoListOffice_MUI')->nullable();
        $table->string('CoListOfficeMLSID')->nullable();
        $table->string('CoListOfficeName')->nullable();
        $table->string('CoListOfficePhone')->nullable();
        $table->text('CommunityType')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('ConditionalDate')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('CondoFee',17,2)->nullable();
        $table->string('CondoFeeFreq')->nullable();
        $table->text('Construction')->nullable();
        $table->char('ContactSellerForShowingYN',1)->nullable();
        $table->string('ContingencyType')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('ContingentExpirationDate')->nullable();
        $table->text('Cooling')->nullable();
        $table->bigInteger('CoSellingAgent_MUI')->nullable();
        $table->string('CoSellingAgentDirectWorkPhone')->nullable();
        $table->string('CoSellingAgentEmail')->nullable();
        $table->string('CoSellingAgentFullName')->nullable();
        $table->string('CoSellingAgentMLSID')->nullable();
        $table->bigInteger('CoSellingOffice_MUI')->nullable();
        $table->string('CoSellingOfficeMLSID')->nullable();
        $table->string('CoSellingOfficeName')->nullable();
        $table->string('CoSellingOfficePhone')->nullable();
        $table->string('CountyOrParish')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('CreatedDate')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('CurrentPrice',16,2)->nullable();
        $table->string('Development')->nullable();
        $table->string('DevelopmentName')->nullable();
        $table->text('DiningDescription')->nullable();
        $table->integer('DOM')->nullable();
        $table->string('ElementarySchool')->nullable();
        $table->string('Elevator')->nullable();
        $table->text('Equipment')->nullable();
        $table->text('ExteriorFeatures')->nullable();
        $table->text('ExteriorFinish')->nullable();
        $table->char('FIRPTAYN',1)->nullable();
        $table->text('Flooring')->nullable();
        $table->text('FloorPlanType')->nullable();
        $table->char('ForeclosedREOYN',1)->nullable();
        $table->string('FullAddress')->nullable();
        $table->text('FurnishedDesc')->nullable();
        $table->string('GarageDesc')->nullable();
        $table->string('GarageDimension')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('GarageSpaces',11,2)->nullable();
        $table->text('GuestHouseDesc')->nullable();
        $table->string('GuestHouseLivingArea')->nullable();
        $table->text('GulfAccessType')->nullable();
        $table->char('GulfAccessYN',1)->nullable();
        $table->text('Heat')->nullable();
        $table->string('HighSchool')->nullable();
        $table->string('HOADesc')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('HOAFee',17,2)->nullable();
        $table->string('HOAFeeFreq')->nullable();
        $table->char('IDXOptInYN',1)->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('InactiveDate')->nullable();
        $table->text('InteriorFeatures')->nullable();
        $table->text('Irrigation')->nullable();
        $table->text('KitchenDescription')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('LandLeaseFee',17,2)->nullable();
        $table->string('LandLeaseFeeFreq')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('LastChangeTimestamp')->nullable();
        $table->string('LastChangeType')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('LastListPrice',16,2)->nullable();
        $table->string('LastStatus')->nullable();
        $table->char('LeaseLimitsYN',1)->nullable();
        $table->integer('LeasesPerYear')->nullable();
        $table->string('LegalDesc')->nullable();
        $table->string('LegalUnit')->nullable();
        $table->bigInteger('ListAgent_MUI')->nullable();
        $table->string('ListAgentDirectWorkPhone')->nullable();
        $table->string('ListAgentEmail')->nullable();
        $table->string('ListAgentFullName')->nullable();
        $table->string('ListAgentMLSID')->nullable();
        $table->char('ListingOnInternetYN',1)->nullable();
        $table->string('ListOfficeMLSID')->nullable();
        $table->string('ListOfficeName')->nullable();
        $table->string('ListOfficePhone')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('ListPrice',16,2)->nullable();
        $table->integer('LotBack')->nullable();
        $table->text('LotDesc')->nullable();
        $table->integer('LotFrontage')->nullable();
        $table->integer('LotLeft')->nullable();
        $table->integer('LotRight')->nullable();
        $table->string('LotUnit')->nullable();
        $table->text('Maintenance')->nullable();
        $table->string('Management')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('MandatoryClubFee',17,2)->nullable();
        $table->string('MandatoryClubFeeFreq')->nullable();
        $table->char('MandatoryHOAYN',1)->nullable();
        $table->text('MasterBathDescription')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('MasterHOAFee',17,2)->nullable();
        $table->string('MasterHOAFeeFreq')->nullable();
        $table->bigInteger('matrix_unique_id')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('MatrixModifiedDT')->nullable();
        $table->string('MiddleSchool')->nullable();
        $table->integer('MinDaysofLease')->nullable();
        $table->string('MLS')->nullable();
        $table->string('MLSAreaMajor')->nullable();
        $table->string('MLSNumber')->nullable();
        $table->integer('NumberofCeilingFans')->nullable();
        $table->integer('NumUnitFloor')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('OffMarketDate')->nullable();
        $table->integer('OneTimeLandLeaseFee')->nullable();
        $table->integer('OneTimeMandatoryClubFee')->nullable();
        $table->integer('OneTimeOtheFee')->nullable();
        $table->integer('OneTimeRecLeaseFee')->nullable();
        $table->integer('OneTimeSpecialAssessmentFee')->nullable();
        $table->integer('OpenHouseCount')->nullable();
        $table->string('OpenHouseUpcoming')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('OriginalListPrice',16,2)->nullable();
        $table->string('OwnershipDesc')->nullable();
        $table->string('ParcelNumber')->nullable();
        $table->text('Parking')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('PendingSaleDate')->nullable();
        $table->string('Pets')->nullable();
        $table->integer('PetsLimitMaxNumber')->nullable();
        $table->integer('PetsLimitMaxWeight')->nullable();
        $table->string('PetsLimitOther')->nullable();
        $table->integer('PhotoCount')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('PhotoModificationTimestamp')->nullable();
        $table->text('Possession')->nullable();
        $table->string('PostalCode')->nullable();
        $table->string('PostalCodePlus4')->nullable();
        $table->char('PostContractServYN',1)->nullable();
        $table->char('PotentialShortSaleYN',1)->nullable();
        $table->char('PresentNegoContYN',1)->nullable();
        $table->decimal('PricePerAcre',14,2)->nullable();
        $table->decimal('PricePerSqFt',14,2)->nullable();
        $table->text('PrivatePoolDesc')->nullable();
        $table->char('PrivatePoolYN',1)->nullable();
        $table->text('PrivateSpaDesc')->nullable();
        $table->char('PrivateSpaYN',1)->nullable();
        $table->char('PropertyAddressonInternetYN',1)->nullable();
        $table->text('PropertyInformation')->nullable();
        $table->string('PropertyType')->nullable();
        $table->integer('Range')->nullable();
        $table->string('RearExposure')->nullable();
        $table->text('Restrictions')->nullable();
        $table->text('Road')->nullable();
        $table->text('Roof')->nullable();
        $table->integer('RoomCount')->nullable();
        $table->integer('Section')->nullable();
        $table->bigInteger('SellingAgent_MUI')->nullable();
        $table->string('SellingAgentDirectWorkPhone')->nullable();
        $table->string('SellingAgentEmail')->nullable();
        $table->string('SellingAgentFullName')->nullable();
        $table->string('SellingAgentMLSID')->nullable();
        $table->bigInteger('SellingOffice_MUI')->nullable();
        $table->string('SellingOfficeMLSID')->nullable();
        $table->string('SellingOfficeName')->nullable();
        $table->string('SellingOfficePhone')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('SellPricePerSqFt',17,2)->nullable();
        $table->text('Sewer')->nullable();
        $table->text('SourceofMeasureLivingArea')->nullable();
        $table->text('SourceofMeasureLotDimensions')->nullable();
        $table->text('SourceofMeasureLotSize')->nullable();
        $table->text('SourceofMeasureTotalArea')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('SpecialAssessment',17,2)->nullable();
        $table->string('SpecialAssessmentFeeFreq')->nullable();
        $table->text('SpecialInformation')->nullable();
        $table->string('StateOrProvince')->nullable();
        $table->string('Status')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('StatusContractualSearchDate')->nullable();
        $table->string('StatusType')->nullable();
        $table->text('StormProtection')->nullable();
        $table->string('StreetDirPrefix')->nullable();
        $table->string('StreetDirSuffix')->nullable();
        $table->string('StreetName')->nullable();
        $table->string('StreetNumber')->nullable();
        $table->string('StreetNumberModifier')->nullable();
        $table->string('StreetSuffix')->nullable();
        $table->string('SubCondoName')->nullable();
        $table->string('SubdivisionNumber')->nullable();
        $table->string('Table')->nullable();
        $table->text('TaxDesc')->nullable();
        $table->string('TaxDistrictType')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('Taxes',17,2)->nullable();
        $table->integer('TaxYear')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('TempOffMarketDate')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('TerminatedDate')->nullable();
        $table->text('Terms')->nullable();
        $table->integer('TotalArea')->nullable();
        $table->integer('TotalFloors')->nullable();
        $table->integer('Township')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('TransferFee',17,2)->nullable();
        $table->integer('UnitCount')->nullable();
        $table->string('UnitFloor')->nullable();
        $table->string('UnitNumber')->nullable();
        $table->integer('UnitsinBuilding')->nullable();
        $table->integer('UnitsinComplex')->nullable();
        $table->text('View')->nullable();
        $table->string('VirtualTourURL')->nullable();
        $table->text('Water')->nullable();
        $table->text('WaterfrontDesc')->nullable();
        $table->char('WaterfrontYN',1)->nullable();
        $table->text('Windows')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('WithdrawnDate')->nullable();
        $table->integer('YearBuilt')->nullable();
        $table->string('ZoningCode')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have reached the MySQL's row size limit:

> Every table (regardless of storage engine) has a maximum row size of
>   65,535 bytes. Storage engines may place additional constraints on this
>   limit, reducing the effective maximum row size.

Read more here [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/column-count-limit.html)